# Node.js HTTP Strings

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given a full HTTP message string, is there facilities in Node.js to parse this? Basically I'm not going to be using the http.createServer function. I already have the full HTTP message through other means (ZMQ), but I need to parse it, which means headers, query strings, post body.. etc.

Furthermore, the same functionality should be able to reverse the process, that is creating a fully formed HTTP response message string. That I can use and pass through different transport (ZMQ).

I know that PHP has [Symfony's HTTP Foundation](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation) (which does what I'm asking). Is there something in Node.js that does a similar thing?

I found this: https://github.com/joyent/http-parser but it's in C++

Comment: is it feasible to use the zmq node binding? https://www.npmjs.org/package/zmq

Comment: Of course I'm using that binding. That's not the problem. I'm getting full HTTP strings coming out of the socket.

Comment: Can't you parse the HTTP request before you send it via ZMQ to node into a format that's easy to deserialize/revert into something that node can understand?

Comment: I could, but I'm not actually in control of the pusher. I want to do this from the receiver side.

Comment: You can pull the requests to the proxy service that, when done with parsing, sends the request parsed into JSON to Node. Parsing the request is tricky, there's no guarantee that you can parse any HTTP request your pusher sends. With a service between your pusher and Node, you can at least deny requests that are invalid and simply work with a predefined parsed request. That way you don't risk crashing Node.

Comment: I would imagine this getting tricky if he wants to support persistent connections ie HTTP 100. ie order has to be preserved for requests/response.

Comment: I have to agree with @N.B. its probably a bad idea to do the parsing of the request outside of the request handling code. Modern HTTP is not as stateless as you might think and order for many operations needs to be preserved for which 0MQ is not really known for. Besides you would probably get far better performance with a load balancer unless you plan on not responding to the request.

Comment: To my knowledge, the only thing that sends anything resembling HTTP via ZeroMQ is Mongrel2, and it uses tagged netstrings to do so. Those aren't remotely close to http requests. If you plan to create Mongrel2 handlers using Node.js - it's a bad idea, and the answer given doesn't take into account multipart forms. I'm not trying to bash the answer (it's a good answer), I just want to clarify further that parsing of HTTP requests shouldn't happen within node. You should deliver a parsed response in format that's easy to handle with Node (which is JSON).

Comment: That's true. I found that out recently. Regardless, he did provide the answer to the question. But why do you think parsing HTTP is so bad in Node? What makes Node so bad at parsing HTTP?

Comment: It's not that Node is bad at parsing, the problem is that it's not the right tool for the job. The example doesn't include more complex requests, and cases when you're bombarded with large requests. In order to properly function, you'd have to take care of all that in Node. Is it not simpler that your JS code gets executed by Node ONLY when the input is right? I'd combine Mongrel2's source files to build a handler that provides simple input for Node that's sent only when parsing is complete and successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the http-parser from within node, but it's not very well documented. I extracted the following example from [the tests](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/08a5b442e42ff67bd5666604eebe69f1b4a1c919/test/simple/test-http-parser.js):

```
var HTTPParser = process.binding('http_parser').HTTPParser,
    CRLF = '\r\n',
    request = new Buffer('POST /it HTTP/1.1' + CRLF +
      'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' + CRLF +
      'Content-Length: 15' + CRLF +
      CRLF +
      'foo=42&bar=1337'),
    parser = new HTTPParser(HTTPParser.REQUEST),
    headers = {},
    body = '';

parser.onHeadersComplete = function(info) {
    headers = info;
};

parser.onBody = function(b, start, len) {
    body = b.slice(start,  start + len).toString();
};

parser.onMessageComplete = function() {
    console.log('message complete');
    console.log('request method: ' + headers.method);
    console.log('request body:\n\n ' + body);
};

parser.execute(request, 0, request.length);
```

Gives the following output:

```
message complete
request method: POST
request body:

 foo=42&bar=1337
```